# Material UI Autocomplete component not showing values from react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to get value from the state for materialUI's autocomplete component.

I am facing the following problem : -

Autocomplte working fine for selecting the value and with onChange function it saving it into the state too.
But when I refresh my page/ re-render it is not showing value on the textfeild(from saved state):

```
<Autocomplete
    name={"TideLocation"}
    disabled={p.disabled}
    options={data_source}
    getOptionLabel={option => option.text}
    inputValue={this.state.tidelocation_searchtext}
    onChange={_this.handleUpdateTideLocationField}
    onNewRequest={_this.handleChangeTideLocation}
    onBlur={_this.handleBlurTideLocationField}
    onUpdateInput={_this.handleUpdateTideLocationField}
      renderInput={(params) => (
       <TextField className="autoCompleteTxt"{...params} label="Location" />
    )}
/>
```

I tried with the debugger and found its getting value in `this.state.tidelocation_searchtext`
but failed to set it with params.

Thanks in advance !!
Ps: I tried with defaultValue and search text nothing worked for me

following is my ONchangeFunction

```
  handleUpdateTideLocationField = (str, value) => {
        debugger
        this.setState({tidelocation_searchtext: value.text});
    }
```

after selecting a value,following value saved in sate :

```
tidelocation_searchtext: "Auckland"
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we can't guess what are the state values and how you rendering the component

Comment: Ok I will add some more information to it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I found the solution all by myself by doing research and several hit and try, following is the solution of my problem:

```
<Autocomplete
  name={"TideLocation"}
  disabled={p.disabled}
  options={data_source.map(option=>option.text)} 
  defaultValue={this.state.tidelocation_searchtext}
  onChange={_this.handleUpdateTideLocationField}
  onNewRequest={_this.handleChangeTideLocation}
  onBlur={_this.handleBlurTideLocationField}
  onUpdateInput={_this.handleUpdateTideLocationField}
  renderInput={(params) => (
  <TextField className="autoCompleteTxt"{...params} label="Location" />
 )}
/>
```

Basically I was doing the following things wrong :

1.There is no need of using input `inputValue={this.state.tidelocation_searchtext}`&  `getOptionLabel={option => option.text}`

2.as my data is in object form I have to convert it into a string so default value can match this from the state value
    `options={data_source.map(option=>option.text)}`

Thank you all for your valuable support and solution !!

Answer (score 2):

Removing `inputValue` has worked for me, even when passing `object` as options.

Using: `"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3"`

Answer (score 1):

You are right, if object type options are passed, material-ui's `AutoComplete` component does not seem to reflect the `value` when mounted. (Perhaps a bug?)

I was able to get around this by passing the proper characters to `inputValue`.

@RebelCoder

Maybe you should have initialized `tidelocation_searchtext`.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was coming from the dropdown z-index which was hidden by another css behaviour.

I added this in a css file :

```
/* Dropdown MUI Component Autocomplete*/
div[role="presentation"].MuiAutocomplete-popper {
  z-index: 1000000;
}
```

And it appeared finally. A bit hacky, but I think it was caused by another library that had something of that kind.

Note that I added several css elements to the selector, because just using the class wasn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

If data/state **not saved externally** f.e. in local storage then it **will be lost on page refresh, always**. It's normal - like RAM memory without power - it (page/app state) only exists in memory !!

It's like using using cookie to keep you logged in.

If you really need such functionality then use f.e. [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

Comment: I am using already using redux for state management, with the help of debugger I can see the state with its value is rendring properly. just not able to passs to to autocomplte > textfeild > params

Comment: setState uses local component state, there is no redux - show this parts

Comment: I am working on docker values are saving into database

Comment: that gives ZERO informations about the problem - every kestroke in search input goes to DB?! input is used for querying DB but entered value IS NOT SAVED/STORED anywhere beside component state (ALWAYS lost on page refresh) - if it must survive browser page refresh then it must be stored persistantly

Comment: if you're using redux then use `mapToStateProps` and `this.props.someSearchText` as `inputValue` - use `dispatch` (and reducer) to change value in store, prop will be updated

Comment: I found the solution to my problem